# tutorial for an alarm needed

Tags: android, android-alarms

I am starting an app for android. I was wondering if anyone had any tutorials to get me going. Something similar to an alarm that goes off on 2 different occasions on specific dates, these dates and times should be obtained from a csv file or something similar so that i can control when and at what time the alarm goes off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at the API Demos project?  It has samples of how to use many of the different API calls, including alarms: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/index.html

Comment: thanks. at first glance i think i need something thats a bit more "idiot proof" but i'll try and give it a shot.

any other suggestions?

Comment: No, not really.  Although a simple google search brought this up: http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/02/android-basics-alarm-service/  Although I can't vouch for it, at first glance it looked okay to me.

Answer (score 0):

See this tutorial: 
http://android-er.blogspot.co.nz/2010/10/simple-example-of-alarm-service-using.html